# PHP Using single Count++ on both loop/conditional & static content?

Tags: php, count, counter

Is it possible to use count++ and print it without conditionals or loop?

Normally I use it on conditionals/loop like example:

```
<?php $count = 1; { while( have_rows('test') ): the_row(); ?>
<a href="#div<?php echo $count;?>">Text <?php echo $count;?></a>
<?php $count++;?>
<?php endwhile; }?>
```

But I want it to use it in stuff like this:

```
<?php $count = 1; {?>
<a href="#div<?php echo $count;?>">Static Text <?php echo $count;?></a>
<a href="#div<?php echo $count;?>">Static Text <?php echo $count;?></a>
<?phpwhile( have_rows('test') ): the_row(); ?>
<a href="#div<?php echo $count;?>">Loop Text <?php echo $count;?></a>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php $count++;?>
<?php}?>
```

How to make the counting work on both static & loop contents?

Comment: Just try it. It will work.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.